# Spring Data JPA Hibernate Duplicate Remote Database schema to Imbedded H2 Instance

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

How do I setup Hibernate and H2 in such a way that it will download table schemas (and stored procs maybe) from a remote database and apply them to the embedded database?

The reason I need to do this is that I have a few tables not modeled by entity classes that aren't auto created by hibernate and I want to test Native Queries against those tables (so if I misspelled a column name or something).

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate or Spring Data JPA won't do this for you.

What you could do get the information from the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://www.h2database.com/html/systemtables.html) and use the information found in there to create DDL statements that you then execute against the local database.

But this is most likely the wrong approach to solving your underlying problem of having two identically databases.
Instead, use a tool like [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) to configure and version control your database setup and then use that to create/update both databases.

Comment: It's for testing. I don't want to touch the actual database, but I want my embedded database to represent the actual one accurately.

Comment: I understand. That is exactly what Flyway and Liquibase are made for. After all, you probably want to update your production DB as well. Or you might want to test against the next version of your DB.